# How to use "git describe" with dev and main (with tags) branches

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, git-tag, git-describe

I'm trying to setup a repository as if it there will be collaboration in the future, but for now it's just me using it.

My intention is to use three branch tiers

1. main: An always working, release branch where every commit is a tagged merge commit from pull requests only (protected).
2. dev: Where development occurs, including small changes.
3. feature branches: for larger/grouped changes, merged into dev

When it comes time for a release, I plan to get dev into the state the repository needs to be for that version, then pull request dev -> master and use GitHub actions to do build checks and ensure the state is valid according to some rules. Then when the pull request is merged, another workflow will tag the release according to more rules (i.e. v1.0.0 and the like).

So far so good, with things looking like this:

```
------------------D (main: v1.0.2)
-----A------B---C/  (dev, C is commit that was used for pull request)
      \E---F/       (my-feature, example feature branch)
```

The problem is that within my build system in several places I want to use:

```
git describe --match v*.* --dirty --always
```

with the intention being that the next commit made after D here would be something like:

```
v1.0.2-1-g7259g4f
```

which would be the case if everything was done on main; however, with this branch setup and the next commit presumably occurring on dev (or a new feature branch) since it would have no direct path backwards to D, `describe` would report based off the previous common ancestor between dev/main, which may also be nothing if this is early enough in the history (just giving a commit hash if --always is used). This would mean that `describe` would only produce meaningful results (in my use case) when run on main only, while I need it to "work" for all branches so that every commit that occurs after a release version is merged into and tagged in main is described relative to that last tag.

This way there is a general sense of progression:

- For dev/feature branch builds: Oh this build is based on version 1.0.2, its 24 commits ahead with this hash for the latest one, and the local repo had uncommitted changes, regardless of which exact branch its on, as that can be added separately or discerned from the commit hash).
- For main builds: This is a build of release version v1.0.2, v1.0.3, etc.

So far I've thought of two workarounds:

1. After the pull request merge commit in main (D here) is tagged, immediately merge it back into dev to establish a common ancestor and backwards path for `describe`:

   ```
    ------------------D   (main: v1.0.2)
    -----A------B---C/\G--(dev, G merge back, will describe like v1.0.2-1-g723...)
          \E---F/         (my-feature, example feature branch)
   ```

   it works, but feels awkward since the merge is essentially just for the tag.
2. Tag each commit in dev that is to be used for pull requests into main with something like `dv1.0.2`. This way all decedents of that commit on dev and derivative branches will react to describe as I want, just with 'dv' instead, while the merge commits in main will still be just 'v'. Practically this will work and allow for identifying builds just as easily, it just adds an extra tag step/more workflow jobs and doesn't look quite as clean.

Is there a better way to achieve this usage of `git describe` or am I stuck using one of the above methods?

Comment: 1. is what I do in my own workflow, and what I recommend. I don't think of it as a work-around, and it's not just for the tag. When you merge main back into dev, you're declaring in an explicit way that you're developing on top of that release, and that will make the development path much clearer in the future when you look at the history over a bunch of releases.

Comment: For what it's worth, I actually prefer to fast-forward merge main back into dev, so I don't have a merge commit. My next commit on dev is just the next feature commit. If you do that at each release, your commit graph collapses to a single point for each release, branching out for features between releases, but collapsing tidily on releases. While absolutely not essential, I find this makes the logs much easier to read and understand.

Comment: But, to finish my story, whether you create a merge commit G or use a fast-forward merge back into dev, I would strongly argue merging main back into dev is the right thing to do in general.

Comment: @joanis I really appreciate sharing your experience. I was planning on initially doing 1) first unless someone else pointed out something I liked better. I know I called it a work around but it did seem like it was at least somewhat of a reasonable approach. I'll play around in my test repo to see if I like the results of using FF for main -> dev, as that sounds like a good suggestion. `When you merge main back into dev, you're declaring in an explicit way that you're developing on top of that release`. This is exactly what I'm going for.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/Name8A9) I have merged dev into master with a non-FF, tagged the merge commit 0.2, and then did several test commits on dev. Then on the [next merge and tag](https://i.imgur.com/e27qZWB.png) this seems to result in the clear collapse into a singular commit you mentioned. So is this what you meant I should do? Checkout master, commit merge dev into it, tag that commit, checkout dev, fast forward master (in)to it, then finally proceed with development and rinse and repeat?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That looks like my repos just after a release.

Comment: @joanis Excellent! I think this works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for posterity I will turn joanis' comments into an answer.

While there are many ways to manage git history, what ended up working for me (in order to enable use of `git describe` as described above), was to handle my branches such that when a release is ready, denoted by a merge into main, that dev and any derivative branches all converge to the same point, such that the head of dev and main point to the same commit immediately afterwards.

This can be accomplished by doing the following (assuming dev is the source branch):

1. `git checkout main`
2. `git pull` (if needed)
3. `git merge dev --no-ff`
4. `git tag vX.Y.Z` (whatever tag you want, if any)
5. 'git checkout dev`
6. `git merge main --ff-only`

Of course, main can be substituted for any branch you want (e.g. release, staging, 2.01, etc.).

After the *next* merge into main this creates a subjectively nice git history view with clear demarcations for each development cycle, as described by joanis:

[image]

Before that next merge the following changes on dev will appear along the same "track" as main.